# GitlabApi POST body merge request

Tags: curl, gitlab, gitlab-api

Maybe anyone has faced similar issue. I am trying to POST the comment on MergeRequest through GitLabAPI. It seems to be simple from the documentation:

`curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxx888" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/11/merge_requests/1/notes?body=[link](https://example.com)"`

I can not really make it working because I got 403 Forbidden. However - if I put the message manually through GUI in the format - `[link](https://example.com)` - it works fine. Has anyone struggled with similar issue?

```
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone had similar issues with that - to fix it there is a need to put body data not as a parameter but as body, so:

`curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxx888" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/11/merge_requests/1/notes --data '{"body"= "[link](https://example.com)"}'`

and in Lambda if someone is using AWS to automate it:

````
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    
gitlab_merge_notify = http.request('POST', gitlab_merge_url,
    headers={'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': 'Curl/0.1','Private-Token': api_key},
    body=json.dumps(dataindict)
    )```
````